# C# WebBrowser proxy для каждой вклдаки

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, браузер, webbrowser

мне нужно реализовать автоматизацию для некоторого онлайн сервиса. Простым решением является использование стандартного компонента - "WebBrowser" или какого-нибудь "headless" браузера, но для выполнения задачи необходимо несколько "вкладок" и при этом каждая вкладка должна работать с определенным прокси. Как это реализовать?. Важно: контент, который подгружает(динамически) страница так же должен загружаться через прокси.

Comment: Отличная задачка по ботоводству, а что имеено не получается?

Comment: Я не могу понять, как мне создать несколько браузеров или "вкладок" с разными прокси, чтобы это было оптимально по памяти. Это нужно для работы с аккаунтами.

Comment: Почему обязательно headless? Можно через Selenium управлять полноценным браузером. А так, каждый экземпляр класса `WebBrowser` (он же Internet Explorer) - это по сути отдельный браузер, которому можно назначить уникальную проксю и независимо работать с полученными веб-страницами. Создайте `List<WebBrowser>`, добавьте в него экземпляры, и работайте с ними обращаясь к этому списку.

Comment: WebBrowser не поддерживает socks4/5 прокси и более того, прокси там меняется через реестр, а для портабл решения не особо хочется трогать его, вдруг у пользователя там например будут какие то настройки. Selenium это драйвер, а значит он будет управлять каким то другим браузером например хромом.., возможности установить прокси для каждой вкладки нет, а создавать кучу объектов браузера очень дорого по памяти, ну например для 10 аккаунтов это уже Гб оперативки, если не больше.

Comment: Ну тогда бы я смотрел в более низкоуровневую реализацию, скажем на базе `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, и обменивался данными с сервером напрямую, эмулируя поведение браузера. Задача не простая. Ну или искать другой headless браузер для C#.